# File path in python

Tags: python, json, file

I'm trying to load the json file but it gives me an error saying `No such file or directory:`

```
with open ('folder1/sub1/sub2/sub2/sub3/file.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
print data
```

The above file main.py is kept outside the `folder1`. All of this is kept under project folder.

So, the directory structure is Project/folder1/sub1/sub2/sub2/sub3/file.json
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you using abs path? It is `'folder1/...'` but not `'/folder1/...'` ? And what's your current dir where you execute the `main.py`

Comment: I omitted the initial slash, but it didnt worked. My `main.py` file is kept under `project` folder

Comment: what's your current dir where you execute the `main.py`, If it not under the `Project`, the real path of `f` if `your_current_dir + '/folder1/...'` but not `Project/folder1/sub1/sub2/sub2/sub3/file.json`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I prefer to point pathes starting from file directory

```
import os
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, 'relative/path/to/file.json')
with open(file_path, 'r') as fi:
    pass
```

this allows not to care about working directory changes. And also this allows to run script from any directory using it's full path.

```
python script/inner/script.py
```

or

```
python script.py
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `os.path.join` method to form the complete path starting from the current directory.

Something like:

```
json_filepath = os.path.join('.', 'folder1', 'sub1', 'sub2', 'sub3', 'file.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

As always, an initial slash indicates that the path starts from the root. Omit the initial slash to indicate that it is a relative path.

Comment: Which "Correct" path?